# Get text before dot character in pentaho PDI

Tags: regex, pentaho

Im getting a text GHIJ.txt and I would like to get only the string before dot. Here
**GHIJ** alone, I used replace string, regex_evaluator with [^.]*  but not getting  result or error.
Recently only I started PDI which component is best for such activity and giving a sample will help.

I tried regex_evaluator but it throws error in group, not sure the purpose of group.
Javascript and replace string also not helping.
Need easy and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I used Regex Evaluation with expression as  ^(.*?)..*

Also enabled 'Create fields for capture groups' and in 'Capture Groups Fields' gave a new field name, type and 'Group' as some name 'A'.

Used the new field name in next component.